# Dimension of restricted root spaces of split Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a real simple **split** Lie algebra. Let $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak k \oplus \mathfrak p$ be the Cartan decomposition. Let $\mathfrak a\subseteq \mathfrak p$ be a maximal abelian subalgebra. Let $\alpha \in \mathfrak a^*$ be a (restricted) root and let $\mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ be its root space.

> Is it true that $\dim \mathfrak g_{\alpha}=1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. See Helgason (Prop. 6.3, [p. 430](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9KFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA430); 6(a), [p. 531](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9KFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA531)) or Onishchik–Vinberg [1990](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1064110) (23–25, [p. 274](https://books.google.com/books?id=TV7sCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA274)).